# Understanding a certain TeX instruction

Tags: learning

I want to understand the TeX instructions

```
  \ifx\@tempb`\edef\next##1{%
```

Especially, I want understand what meaning of `` ` `` symbol before `\edef`.
As I know `ifx` compare two statements, symbol `` ` ``  for symbol taking - `` `\A `` takes a code of symbol `A`. 
Or I am wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I have replaced the ` character with a ' character as there is an interference with TeX.SX formatting and the TeX character.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `` ` `` there has no connection to the use of `` ` `` to get the character code of a symbol, it should be read as

```
\ifx\@tempb`
    \edef\next....
```

that is if the two tokens `\@tempb` and `` ` `` are equal then define `\next` to be something. They will be equal if for example `\@tempb` had been defined by

```
\let\@tempb=`
```

or (if I recognise that code fragment:-) if it had been defined by `\futurelet` rather than `\let`.

Comment: Yes, David, this is fragment from one of yours answers on my question. I want understand those deeper. Thanks for explanation.